# ByRef parameter with Type Conversion

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion

I did create a XDateTime class that is able to handle inaccurate date and time.

This class has all the CType operators required to convert to and from a string and it has been fully tested during the last months.

```
    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal xDateTime As FrameworkBL.XDateTime) As String
    Dim retrunValue As String = Nothing

    If xDateTime Is Nothing Then
        retrunValue = Nothing
    Else
        retrunValue = xDateTime.StringValue
    End If

    Return retrunValue
End Operator

Public Shared Narrowing Operator CType(ByVal value As String) As FrameworkBL.XDateTime
    Dim returnValue As FrameworkBL.XDateTime = Nothing


    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) Then
        returnValue = Nothing
    Else
        returnValue = New FrameworkBL.XDateTime(value)
    End If

    Return returnValue

End Operator
```

However, when a ByRef object parameter return a string, my CType operators seems to be ignored and a cast Exception is raised.

```
    Private Sub Test()
    Dim myXDateTime As FrameworkBL.XDateTime

    myXDateTime = "200101010000007" 'Ok
    Me.Temp1(myXDateTime) 'Ok
    Me.Temp2(myXDateTime) 'Ok
    Me.Temp3(myXDateTime) 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'FrameworkBL.XDateTime'

End Sub

Private Sub Temp1(ByRef myObject As String)
    myObject = "200201010000007"
End Sub

Private Sub Temp2(ByRef myObject As XDateTime)
    myObject = "200301010000007"
End Sub

Private Sub Temp3(ByRef myObject As Object)
    myObject = "200401010000007"
End Sub
```

This kind of problem is [documented by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184529.aspx) but I couldn't find a working solution to fix this problem.  Am I in a dead end or is there an option that would allow me to keep my ByRef Object parameter??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is not to write this code. In fact, your code shouldn’t even compile, and never mind the `ByRef`. You simply cannot assign a string to an `Object`, and rightly so. You should enable `Option Strict On` in your project settings.

This is the correct and expected behaviour.

Apart from that, your operator implementations can (and should) be drastically shortened by taking advantage of the VB `If` operator. This makes the redundant initialisation and assignments go away:

```
Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal xDateTime As XDateTime) As String
    Return If(xDateTime Is Nothing, Nothing, xDateTime.StringValue)
End Operator
```

Same for the other way round. That said, I don’t think conversion operators should ever work on `Nothing` values. This just makes `Nothing` creep into code where it shouldn’t.